# Different cookies expire time between browser and local server

Tags: cookies

We use cookie to remember user's login status. The cookie's expire time in my code is all right, but when redirected to another page, the cookie is missing. Then I modify the code, add 100 years to the cookie's expire time. Finally, the browser shows the expire time is 2115-07-23.

Here is the code picture and local time:

[image: cookie]

A few minutes later,the system broken down. When I open the program again, it is all right! It's unbelievable!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly format the picture and fix some grammar errors. Please edit in to povide more additional information that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thank  you  very much!